# Levy Flights Cuckoo Search algorithm Python

Tags: python, optimization, random, probability, distribution

I am implementing a cuckoo search algorithm for the TSP. However i am struggling with the part of levy flights in the implementation to create ranges. The levy flight should be between 0 and 1. See picture below for more explanation. Is there anyone who could help me out with the python implementation?

Currently i have the following code:

def levyFlight(u):
return u/math.pow(1-u, 1.6)

def randF():
return uniform(0.0001, 0.9999)

levy = levyFlight(randF())

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem somewhere with your definition and use of Levy Flights. First, according to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight), CDF is equal to

CDF(u|a) = 1 - u<sup>-a</sup>

which is also stated in the [knaidoo](https://knaidoo29.github.io/mistreedoc/levy_flight.html) notebook (set *t<sub>0</sub>*=1 and replace *t* with *u*).

Sampling routine for a given *a* would be

```
def levyFlight(u, a=1.6):
    return 1.0/(1.0-u)**(1.0/a)
```

which is the same thing knaidoo is doing in his [mistree](https://github.com/knaidoo29/mistree/blob/master/mistree/levy_flight/levy_flight.py) package.

But in both cases (yours and mine/knaidoo), output of Levy Flights sampling routine CANNOT be within [0...1] interval as you want - you could check it manually setting U(0,1) random number say to 0.9 and calculate for *a*=1.6, I'm getting back 4.22